# Calculate time between UTC in R

Tags: r, time, utc

So I have a series of values in two columns in this format

**6/14/1998 17:30** | **6/16/1998 1:45**

I would like to calculate the time between this two timestamps in R.

Basically, calculate the number of hours between t1 and t2. Could you please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, why has my question been downvoted. So much snark in SO against newbies. This was a genuine question. Hmmph. Thanks to @dirk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elementary, and covered a million times:

```
R> difftime(strptime("6/16/1998 01:45", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC"),
+           strptime("6/14/1998 17:30", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC"),
+           unit="min")     
Time difference of 1935 mins
R>
```

See `help(difftime)` and `help(strptime)`.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting it in days. But I am facing problem in getting it in minutes. 

Error: unexpected '=' in:
"         +           strptime("6/14/1998 17:30", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC"),
         +           units="

Comment: You do not enter the '+', that is (standard R) convention for code continued on the next line.